# Retrieve data from MySQL into dynamically input using PHP & Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, data-retrieval

I'm building some application which is retrieving data from MySql database into a dynamically inputs using PHP & Ajax when I'm retrieving data for this input it always shown in the next one but it suppose shown in the div that I mentioned in Ajax code.

This picture will explain my problem clearly sorry for my language English is not my first language.

[image]

My html code:

```
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-lg-4"></label>
                      <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="box">
                          <header>
                            <h5>تفاصيل الطلب</h5>
                            </header>
                            <div class="body">
                              <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="control-label col-lg-2">الصنف</label>
                                  <div class="col-lg-10">
                                      <select id="itemname" name="itemname[]" class="form-control">
                                        <option disabled selected>اختر الصنف</option>
                                        <?php echo getValues($pdo); ?>
                                      </select>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-lg-2">السعر</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                  <input type="text" id="price" name="price[]" placeholder="-" readonly class="form-control">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-lg-2">الكمية</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity" value="0" min="1">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

PHP file:

```
<?php    
    require 'DBConnection.php';
    $code='';
    if(isset($_POST["code"])){
        $id = $_POST["code"];
        $get_c = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM all_menu WHERE `item_name` = '".$id."'");
        $get_c->execute(); 
        while ($row = $get_c->fetch()) {
            $code .= $row['price'];
        }
        echo $code;
    }
?>
```

JQuery code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i=1;
    $('#add').click(function(){
    i++;
    $('#append').append('<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-lg-4"></label><div class="col-lg-4"><div class="box"><header><h5>تفاصيل الطلب</h5></header><div class="body"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-lg-2">الصنف</label><div class="col-lg-10"><select id="itemname'+i+'" name="itemname[]" class="form-control"><option disabled selected>اختر الصنف</option><?php echo getValues($pdo); ?></select></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-lg-2">السعر</label><div class="col-lg-10"><input type="text" id="price'+i+'" name="price[]" placeholder="-" readonly class="form-control"></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-lg-2">الكمية</label><div class="col-lg-10"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity" value="0" min="1"></div></div></div></div></div></div>');
    $('#itemname'+i+'').change(function(){
      var code = $(this).val();  
       $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'pages/GetPrice.php',
          data:{code:code},
          success: function(data){
            document.getElementById("price"+i+"").value = data;
          },
          error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
            alert(errorThrown);
          }
       });
    });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: In the line that starts `$('#append').append` I’m seeing JS concatenation and PHP interpolation. It might be 100% correct, but it is really hard to debug. Maybe inspect the DOM to make sure it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Yes it is. But it’s not the DOM. I just figured out that we have to use class for getting the elements not IDs.

Answer (score 2):

Things like this will get a lot easier, as soon as you let go of that "newbie habit" of always trying to select elements by ID only.

The *only* thing that is different in all those individual `change` handler functions you are appending to each new select element, is the ID of the price field you want to write the output into. But you don't *need to* select that element by ID, there are other ways - in this case, you should "navigate" to it, based on its position in the DOM, in relation to its corresponding select field.

As soon as you do that, this doesn't need X separate handler functions for X separate select fields any more - but just a single one. And if you set it up using [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), then you don't need to explicitly add it to each and every new select element you create any more either.

The event delegation part would be something like this:

```
$(document).on('change', '[name="itemname[]"]', function() { ... } );
```

You do this *once*, and it will handle change events on all elements with `name="itemname[]"` anywhere in the document - already existing ones, as well as *future* ones that will only be added later.

As for the part of finding the matching price field - for that, you simply navigate up from the select field to a common ancestor of the two - in this case, the `.body` wrapper element should be suitable - and then you look for a price field *inside* of that element.

The select field the event happened upon can be accessed using `$(this)`, and to go up and find a specific ancestor element, jQuery provides the `parents` method - so to access the corresponding price field, you would use something like this:

```
$(this).parents('.body').find('[name="price[]"]').val(data);
```

Since there are no element IDs involved here any more now, and all element selection happens based on other factors, like the `name` attribute and position in the DOM, you can completely go without any `...'+i+'...` stuff in your element creation. Just don't give those elements any IDs at all.

Comment: You’re completely right and I got the point very well, I have read something like this before that we have to use the class in this case not selecting elements by IDs

Comment: But my mind dose not able to implement the right solution technically. So please you seems like someone who familiar with JQuery can you please edit on my JQuery code to try your solution more easier. And I really appreciated.

Comment: Updated:
I just implemented your solution just like this but nothing happened yet!
Here is the code:
`$(document).on('change', 'name="itemname[]"', function() {
    var code = $(this).val();  
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'pages/GetPrice.php',
      data:{code:code},
      success: function(data){
        $(this).parents('.body').find('name="price[]"').val(data);
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
        alert(errorThrown);
      }
    });
  });`

Comment: Sorry, I had the attribute selectors slightly wrong - these need to be `[name="itemname[]"]` and `[name="price[]"]`. I created a basic example based on your code (no modifications to the HTML, apart from providing some actual options to test), and replaced the AJAX portion with simply writing the value of the chosen option into the input field below, but you can see the principle works: https://jsfiddle.net/u1y9srpw/

Comment: Man I'm really appreciated. thanks a lot