# Send form inside a while with java, ajax php

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

**I have the following html code with a form**

```
<form id="msg-form-nota"> 
<input type="hidden" name="id_nota" id="id_nota" value="${project.id}">
<label for="textfield">Calificación obtenida:</label>
<input type="text" name="nota" id="nota" class="form-control form-control-sm" value="${project.nota}" placeholder="Introducir calificación"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Añadir/modificar calificación">
</form>
```

and then I use the following javascript/ajax code to manage the form

```
$('#msg-form-nota').submit(e => {    
  
    e.preventDefault();
      const postData = {
    
      nota: $('#nota').val(),
      id: $('#id_nota').val()
     
    };
    const url ='accion.php';
    
    $.post(url, postData, (response) => {
      toastr.success('añadidas!', 'Actualización ', {"hideDuration": 1500});
      
    
    });
 });
```

The problem that I detect and I don't know how to solve is that, for example, when using a while, 5 forms are created with the same name id, if I use the first form that loads me it works without problem, but if I use the rest, the form does not It works if not that all the content of the form goes to the url as if the method were a get, what can I do? Thank you

Comment: IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document, so if you are outputting this form multiple times in a loop, then changing those IDs is the first thing you need to do. Either append some sort loop counter, so that you get "numbered IDs" - or move away from always trying to identify elements by ID in the first place. (Some thoughts on that - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69642787/1427878)

Comment: [tag:java] != [tag:javascript]

Comment: Yes, I had thought of establishing a numerical id for each form, but in this case, how can I identify in js which form I am sending?

Comment: ID attributes are really a lot trickier to use within loops than other methods involving other selection methods such as the `event`, `event.target`, various parent/sibling/child selectors and also `querySelector` - using those in combination offers great flexibility and generally simplifies the whole process. In your HTML the `submit` button invokes an `event` - from that event it is trivial to find the various input elements and thus their values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to completely remove the ID attributes from your forms/elements you can quite easily simplify the entire code by using a `FormData` object with a reference to the `form` supplied as the single argument. The `FormData` object would collate the various input elements for use in the ajax request - thus negating the need to even try to identify the individual input elements explicitly.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[type="submit"]').forEach(input => input.addEventListener('click',e=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  /*
    The `submit` button raised the event so the `event.target` refers to that button.
    From the button we know the `form` is the parentNode - but you can use `closest`
    to find the parent form.
  */
  let fd = new FormData( e.target.parentNode );
  
  fetch( 'accion.php', { method:'post', body:fd })
    .then(r=>r.text())
    .then(data=>{
      console.log(data);
      
      // call your success function.
      toastr.success('añadidas!', 'Actualización ', {
        "hideDuration": 1500
      });
    });
}))
```

```html
<form data-id='msg-form-nota'>
  <input type='hidden' name='id_nota' value='123' />
  <label>
        Calificación obtenida:
        <input type='text' name='nota' class='form-control form-control-sm' value='Geronimo' placeholder='Introducir calificación' />
    </label>
  <input type='submit' class='btn btn-success btn-sm' value='Añadir/modificar calificación' />
</form>

<form data-id='msg-form-nota'>
  <input type='hidden' name='id_nota' value='456' />
  <label>
        Calificación obtenida:
        <input type='text' name='nota' class='form-control form-control-sm' value='Fred Flintsone' placeholder='Introducir calificación' />
    </label>
  <input type='submit' class='btn btn-success btn-sm' value='Añadir/modificar calificación' />
</form>

<form data-id='msg-form-nota'>
  <input type='hidden' name='id_nota' value='789' />
  <label>
        Calificación obtenida:
        <input type='text' name='nota' class='form-control form-control-sm' value='Spitfire' placeholder='Introducir calificación' />
    </label>
  <input type='submit' class='btn btn-success btn-sm' value='Añadir/modificar calificación' />
</form>
```

---

In the PHP script `accion.php` there will be 2 POST parameters sent by the `fetch` request. These two parameters have the same names as the form input elements. For instance:-

```
<?php

    #accion.php
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset(
        $_POST['id_nota'],
        $_POST['nota']
    )){
        // ... etc do whatever
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! For what I have been able to test the form, it is always executed, but as I identify the inputs, in the console.log it appears to me as the entire raw type page, that is, I do not have the form fields

something like this appears to me   IGFQUnARdNmHh3mJd2epg3cWpmcHFnZ3ICvZd4eJiXd3mYN3BqZ3BwaWdx/j8tAsctBJh+r69+TX6trX5kkJBkTWSSk2P8zX2vrn5Ofq6ufmWQkGVOaouMaeIfBHIfAAMASv/rBH4FxQAlADMAQABAQD03LQ0ABAEFKRUOAwQBAkIABQUAUwAAABRDAAEBAlEAAgINQwYBBAQDUwADAxUDRCcmPz0mMyczJhUaJQcTKwEmJjU

Comment: ? Forgive me but I do not understand what you mean - could you try to clarify `it is always executed` and also where that random string `IGFQUnARdNmHh3...QcTKwEmJjU` is coming from

Comment: My question was how I go through the method that has indicated the input values ​​to the php , I have reviewed console.log(data) and it has shown me those characters...

Comment: I made a small change above that shows some php.... is that what you mean?

Comment: ok, it was indeed that piece of php, which I thought had to be different, now I have another added problem, I have added a second form with a field of observations and another of id, the script would be the same? because the first form if send, the second does not, in short now each while, has two forms

Comment: 2 forms **could** be combined into a single AJAX request using the `FormData` approach perhaps but individually they will operate as distinct entities... This new problem sounds like a new question as the parameters of this question have changed by the sounds of things. Perhaps accept an answer or close the question  and then perhaps ask a new one?! In the above however please note that the POST variables are `as named` in the form rather than as supplied in **your** original ajax request!

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm new to the platform and I don't understand it at the moment, do I have another question about the two forms?

Comment: No problem but if questions change radically it can make answers appear wholly inaccurate when viewed later. Please feel free to post a link here to a new question if you feel that the facts merit one and it is related to this initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue, as your question implies, is because you're repeating the same `id` attribute multiple times as the HTML is generated in a loop.

The best way to fix this is to use common `class` attributes on the elements instead. Then you can target the specific instance which from the `target` property of the event which is raised and passed as an argument to the event handler function. You can also use DOM traversal methods to find the related elements and retrieve their values.

Also note that I wrapped the `input` *within* the `label` element. This removes the need for the `for` and `id` attributes on those elements, but retains the same functionality.

```js
$('.msg-form-nota').on('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let $form = $(e.target);
  
  const postData = {
    nota: $form.find('.nota').val(),
    id: $form.find('.id_nota').val()
  };
  
  console.log(postData);
  
  /* make your AJAX request here... */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="msg-form-nota">
  <input type="hidden" name="id_nota" class="id_nota" value="ID_001">
  <label>
    Calificación obtenida:
    <input type="text" name="nota" class="nota form-control form-control-sm" value="Nota_001" placeholder="Introducir calificación">   
  </label>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Añadir/modificar calificación">
</form>

<form class="msg-form-nota">
  <input type="hidden" name="id_nota" class="id_nota" value="ID_002">
  <label>
    Calificación obtenida:
    <input type="text" name="nota" class="nota form-control form-control-sm" value="Nota_002" placeholder="Introducir calificación">   
  </label>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Añadir/modificar calificación">
</form>

<form class="msg-form-nota">
  <input type="hidden" name="id_nota" class="id_nota" value="ID_003">
  <label>
    Calificación obtenida:
    <input type="text" name="nota" class="nota form-control form-control-sm" value="Nota_003" placeholder="Introducir calificación">   
  </label>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Añadir/modificar calificación">
</form>
```