# Looping Item, with autofill object using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Trying to make the item to be auto fill when select the item. But the item is in looping with will result using the same id if jQuery, so what is the best  method for me? like in the image where user pick the item, then the data will be autofill

```
$countItem = 0;
                                            foreach($SopProcess AS $process)
                                            {
                                            
                                            $countItem++;
                                            if($process["item_proc_det"]== 2){
                                            echo '<div class="col-md-6 col-12">
                                             <div class="mb-1">
                                                     <label class="form-label" >Activity:</label>
                                                     <input type="input"  class="form-control" value="'.$process["name_process"].' '. $process["item_proc_num"].'"  readonly/>
                                                     <input type="hidden"  id="postcode"  class="form-control" value="'.$process["item_proc_num"].'"  readonly/>
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                             <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
                                             <div class="mb-1">
                                             <label class="form-label" >Substance Use</label>
                                             <fieldset>
                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                    <select class="form-select" id="substance'.$countItem.'"  name="item_media[]" required>
                                                    <option value="">Please Select</option>';
                                                        
                                                            foreach($treat as $item_media){
                                                                $id =  $item_media['media_treat_id'];
                                                                $name =  $item_media['media_treat_brand'];
                                                                echo "<option value='$id'>$name</option>";
                                                            }
                                                    echo'   
                                                    </select>
                                                    <input type="nu" id="valueitem'.$countItem.'" class="form-control" placeholder="Input amount use" aria-label="Amount" />
                                                    <select class="form-select" id="basicSelect" id="unititem'.$countItem.'" name="item_media[]" required>
                                                    <option value="">Select Unit</option>';
                                                        
                                                                echo "
                                                                <option value='3'>ml</option>
                                                                <option value='2'>g</option>
                                                                <option value='7'>Unit</option>";
                                                    echo'   
                                                    </select>
                                                    </div>
                                                </fieldset>
                                             </div>
                                          </div>
                                            
                                           
                                             ';
}}
```

For Javascript

```
$$('#substance').on('change', function(){
        
        var activityID = $('#substance').val();
        if(itemId){
            $.ajax({type:'POST',
                url:'?syspath=ajax&controller=ajax&action=generateItemValue',
                data: { 'activitiyNum': itemNumID, 'sraID': sraID, 'seasonID':seasonID,'DetAct': actID },
                
                success:function(html){
             
                        $('#valueitem').html(html);
                        $('#unititem').html(html);
        
                }
            });
        }else{
            ('#itemName').html('<option value="">Select Activity number first</option>'); 
        }
    })
```

I am expecting, the data on the valueitem and unititem will be filled based on the item that were select by the user, but I think am using the wrong way as ID must be unique. I need some help a proper way to use the js or query in which the data will be auto fill even the object are in looping

Comment: My two cents on that matter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69642787/1427878

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link, before this I try fail, but something I change and its work, now just need to think how to make it available in select properties

Comment: @CBroe I try to use like the method you shared, it run, but when I try to run it in success:function it fail to do so   ---
                success:function(data)
                    var object = JSON.parse(data);
                     value = object.itemValue;
                     unit = object.itemUnit;
                    $(this).parents('.body-media').find('[name="value_media[]"]').val(value);
                    $(this).parents('.body-media').find('[name="unit_media[]"]').val(unit);

Comment: Can't currently say anything about that, other than that neither elements with the class `body-media` nor the field name `value_media[]` appear to be part of the HTML you have shown us so far.

Comment: I have found, way somehow, I need to set the $this as context. as before I cannot send the data in success:fuction.