# How to make dynamically added id and change its class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code that add new row in table by pushing add row button. The one field in this row is file type input.

input file is hidden and replaced by "upload image". when I choose image it shows image preview instead of "upload image".

The problem is here: when I add new row it works only for the first row.
Can you help me to find the solution how to make unique ID for each "upload-file" id and change its class to hide/show?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $("#add_row2").click(function() {
    $('#addrQual' + i).html("<td>" + (i + 1) + "</td><td><div class='image-upload'><label for='upload-file'><img class='attach-doc' src='https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/thumbnails/015/337/675/small/transparent-upload-icon-free-png.png' style='height: 48px'></label><input id='upload-file' type='file' name='img[" + i + "]'/></div><div id='thumbnail'></div></td><td><input class='form-control' type='text' name='name[]'></td><td><input class='form-control' type='text' name='type[]'></td>");
    $('#tab_logicQual').append('<tr id="addrQual' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');

    i++;
  });
  $("#delete_row2").click(function() {
    if (i > 1) {
      $("#addrQual" + (i - 1)).html('');
      i--;
    }
  });
});


$('div').on('click', '.closeDiv', function() {
  $(this).prev().remove();
  $(this).remove();
  $('#upload-file').val("");
  $('.image-upload').css('display', 'block');

});
var fileDiv = document.getElementById("upload");
var fileInput = document.getElementById("upload-file");

fileInput.addEventListener("change", function(e) {

  var filesVAR = this.files;
  showThumbnail(filesVAR);

}, false);

function showThumbnail(files) {
  var file = files[0]
  var thumbnail = document.getElementById("thumbnail");
  var pDiv = document.createElement("div");
  var image = document.createElement("img");
  var div = document.createElement("div");

  pDiv.setAttribute('class', 'pDiv');
  thumbnail.appendChild(pDiv);

  image.setAttribute('class', 'img-preview');
  pDiv.appendChild(image)

  div.innerHTML = "x";
  div.setAttribute('class', 'closeDiv');
  pDiv.appendChild(div)

  image.file = file;
  var reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = (function(aImg) {
    return function(e) {
      aImg.src = e.target.result;
    };
  }(image))
  var ret = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  image.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 100, 100);
    $('.image-upload').css('display', 'none');
  }
};
```

```css
.image-upload>input {
  display: none;
}

.attach-doc {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.img-preview {
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
  float: left;
}

.closeDiv {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  margin: 2px -10px;
}

.pDiv {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" type="button" id="add_row2">Add row</button>
<button class="btn" type="button" id="delete_row2">Delete row</button>

<table class="table" id="tab_logicQual">
  <thead>
    <tr VALIGN=MIDDLE ALIGN=CENTER>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id='addrQual0' class="fieldGroup">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <div class="image-upload">
          <label for="upload-file"><img class='attach-doc' src='https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/thumbnails/015/337/675/small/transparent-upload-icon-free-png.png' style='height: 48px'></label>
          <input id="upload-file" type="file" name='img[]' />
        </div>
        <div id="thumbnail"></div>
      </td>
      <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name='name[]'></td>
      <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name='type[]'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='addrQual1'></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: First problem is that you will have multiple elements with the id `upload-file`, ID must be unique. Try use class

Comment: Second problem is that you are using dynamic IDs - there's rarely a good case for this that some other mechanism (eg DOM traversal or data- attributes) would not fit better.

Comment: Best way to avoid trouble using IDs - is to not use IDs in the first place. Stick your file input field _into_ the label element - then the label is automatically associated with that field, so you won't need `for` and an ID on the input field any more. Handle the rest via classes instead of IDs - and by making use of the _relation_ which the elements have to each other in the DOM, https://stackoverflow.com/a/69642787/1427878

Comment: Instead of creating the click handler for each button individually, you can use jQuery's event delegation [see .on() docs further down - Direct and delegated event handlers](https://api.jquery.com/on/). It lets you define handlers for elements that don't exist yet.